# Python: subprocess distinguish between killed and terminated process

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a python program which call another python program using `subprocess.run`, the called python program in turns call an executable using `subprocess.run`.

Following a simple example

a.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

res = subprocess.run(['./b.py'])

retcode = res.returncode

if retcode > 0:
    print(f'a.py: Errored, retcode: {retcode}')
elif retcode < 0:
    print(f'a.py: Killed, retcode: {retcode}')
else:
    print(f'a.py: Completed, retcode: {retcode}')
```

b.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

res = subprocess.run(['./c.sh'])
retcode = res.returncode
print(f"b.py: process exited with {retcode}")
sys.exit(retcode)
```

c.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sleep 300
```

If I run `a.py`  and then `kill -9 <c.sh pid>` I receive the following output

```bash
$ ./a.py       
b.py: process exited with -9
a.py: Errored, retcode: 247
```

What I want to achieve instead is to be able to tell from `a.py`  that the `c.sh` script was killed, that is, I expect the following output:

```bash
$ ./a.py   
b.py: process exited with -9
a.py: Killed, retcode: -9
```

As far as I understood the problem lies in the `sys.exit(retcode)` instruction where something like `-9%256` is performed and so I'm unable to tell if `c.sh` was killed or errored.

How can I detect the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Interestingly enough, this is my output when I run your scripts and kill the c.sh one 
`$ ./a.py

./c.sh: line 2: 23824 Killed sleep 300
b.py: process exited with 137
a.py: Errored, retcode: 137`

Comment: @Matthias, i think you are killing the `sleep` process instead of the `c.sh`, at least this is what I receive when killing `sleep` instead of `c.sh`

Comment: yes that is correct, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html
The signal haves special meaning, greater than 128, lower or equal to 255.
You can detect the difference with this information.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to derive the original exit code using the provided table, in particular in `a.py` if retcode > 128 I subtract 256 to obtain the original one

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status
> (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer,
> zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is
> considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like. **Most systems
> require it to be in the range 0-127**, and produce undefined results
> otherwise. Some systems have a convention for assigning specific
> meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally
> underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax
> errors and 1 for all other kind of errors.

You can't just pass the `-9` code to `sys.exit()`. What you can do is make a function within module `b.py` and call that from `a.py`. Script `a.py` can then check for the return number of `b` and print the appropriate message. `a.py` should check the `retcode` of subprocess `b` only to check whether `b` terminated without errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I overlooked the documentation while researching and missed these bits. Unfortunately I must stick with the `subrocess.run` approach as both python and native executables can be invoked by `a.py`